# User A gets logged off from client when User B remotely connects to client

Tags: remote-desktop

we have a physical client where a User A is logged in.
When a User B is connecting to that client remotely, User A gets logged off.

Is this intended to happen? Is there a way to stop User B from logging off User A when connecting to the client?

If there have to be done some changes: Is it possible to do them via Intune? We manage all clients over Intune.

Thx

Comment: If this is Windows and you are using RDP, then what you see is normal. You can try TeamViewer, Radmin and like tools to access User A when they are using the computer.

Comment: Usually they are not logged out, per se (once they log back in, their session is as they left it) but you are correct windows will only allow one user to run an interactive session at a time.

Comment: The Problem is: User A is constantly receiving and sending mails or something like that and this User needs to stay logged in and continue with what he's doing. There's even a software installed that is called "Don't sleep" ... but it doesn't work.

Comment: This isn't a sleep thing. Microsoft intentionally allows exactly one user to use a Desktop sku product at a time. if you want more than that, then you have to pay for Windows Server. Server will allow two concurrent RDP users at a time for free, and that can be increased with the appropriate licensing.

Comment: In addition to my question: Is it possible to connect remotly with User A and when the RDP session gets closed the local session of User A will continue?